# How to know when the context menu of a control has been shown

Tags: .net, winforms, tooltip, contextmenu

I have a control that draws a diagram, and I show a tooltip when the user is hover an object.

I have also implemented the functionality to show a context menu when you right click the object.

The logic for showing the tooltip is `OnMouseMove()`, but the contextmenu is associated to the control, so its shown by .NET.

The problem is that when I show the context menu, then is shown the tooltip hover the context menu.

Comment: Can you [check to see if any mouse buttons are pressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons.aspx) before showing the tooltip?

Comment: Could you post the code section which shows the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ContextMenu.PopUp Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.popup.aspx) in conjunction with the [ToolTip.Active Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.active.aspx) so that every time your context menu is being shown, you will deactivate the tooltips for the controls.